# Dell Quickset application

Tags: nvidia, dell, battery

Is there any way to install or unlock some features of Dell Quickset application in Ubuntu?

I'm very new to using Ubuntu and Linux, but within Dell Quickset there's a option do disable Dell Inteligent Display and Dell Extended Battery Life.

Those two options cause my screen to dim automatically whenever the screen is composed mostly of dark colors.

If there is any way to disable it in Ubuntu or even to install this application, I'm very grateful to whoever find out.

My specs:
Dell 14r 5437, Nvidia 750, 1TB SSD, 8GB RAM. Running Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

The official [Dell QuickSet application](https://www.dell.com/support/home/in/en/inbsd1/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=dd43y) is a Windows-only application.
Unfortunately there is no Ubuntu alternative.